# Validar importación masiva con Maatwebsite-excel en Laravel 5.5

Tags: excel, validación, maatwebsite

Estoy realizando importación masiva con Maatwebsite en Laravel 5.5.28, el detalle es que tengo problemas cuando un registro ya está en la base de datos MySQL. no se como validar que solo inserte los datos que no están existentes.

Esta es mi función dentro del controlador:

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{       
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Excel::import(new ProductsImport, $file);
    return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('info', 'Importación 
    realizada con éxito');
}
```

y esta es mi modelo de importación:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ProductsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product
        ([
             'folio' => $row['folio'],//a
             'a_paterno' => $row['a_paterno'], //b
             'a_materno' => $row['a_materno'], //c
             'nombres' => $row['nombres'], //d
             'telefono' => $row['telefono'], //e
             'siglas' => $row['siglas'], //f
             'oficina_comercial' => $row['oficina_comercial'], //g
             'centro_trabajo' => $row['centro_trabajo'], //h
             'zona' => $row['zona'], //i
             'estado' => $row['estado'], //j
             'folio_instalado' => $row['folio_instalado'], //k
             'num_serv_instalado' => $row['num_serv_instalado'], //l
             'observaciones' => $row['observaciones'], //m
             'usuario_creador' => $row['usuario_creador'], //n
             'usuario_modif' => $row['usuario_modif'], //o
             'created_at' => $row['created_at'], //p
             'updated_at' => $row['updated_at'], //q
        ]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Implementar `WithValidation` y en el metodo Validar poner como esta en la documentacion, pero opuesto:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'folio' => Rule::notIn(['vacio o null'])
    ];
}
```

Es una ayuda, pero mejor lo entenderas si lees la doc: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#row-validation

Este Video puede Ayudar mucho: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2AUH9w9XaA&ab_channel=QiroLab

Comment: Edita tu respuesta para que sea mas clara y no le proveas link fuera del sitio para no dejar una respuesta mas concisa. Este sitio es justamente para obtener respuestas.